# SQL: процедура T-SQL с использованием псевдонимов (алиасов) столбцов

Tags: sql, sql-server, процедуры

Пытаюсь создать такую процедуру:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE accord
AS
UPDATE Отдел
SET Отдел.Отдел_кол=Var1, Отдел.Отдел_зарп=Var2
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) Var1, SUM(Сотрудник.Оклад) Var2
FROM Сотрудник WHERE Отдел.Отдел_номер=Сотрудник.Отдел)
WHERE Отдел.Отдел_номер IN (SELECT Отдел FROM Сотрудник);
```

Ругается на Var1 и Var2 (недопустимое имя столбца).
Такой код работает:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE accord
AS
SELECT COUNT(*) Var1, SUM(Сотрудник.Оклад) Var2
FROM Сотрудник
```

То есть в процедуре почему-то не получается использовать псевдонимы из подзапроса. А мне это необходимо, чтобы не делать лишние SELECT в процедуре (для каждого столбца свой).

Comment: Подзапрос ОБЯЗАН иметь алиас. Поле подзапроса ОБЯЗАНО иметь алиас подзапроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не работает, потому что  для подзапроса обязательно нужно указать алиас.
Вообще, сомневаюсь что результат выполнения запроса будет соответствовать ожиданиям - лучше переписать.

Вариант с `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE o
SET [Отдел_кол] = s.Var1,
    [Отдел_зарп] = s.Var2
FROM [Отдел] o
    JOIN (
        SELECT [Отдел],
            COUNT(*) AS Var1,
            SUM([Оклад]) AS Var2
        FROM Сотрудник 
        GROUP BY [Отдел]
    ) s ON s.[Отдел] = o.Отдел_номер
```

Вариант с `APPLY`:

```
UPDATE o
SET [Отдел_кол] = s.Var1,
    [Отдел_зарп] = s.Var2
FROM [Отдел] o
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS Var1,
            SUM([Оклад]) AS Var2
        FROM Сотрудник 
        WHERE Отдел = o.Отдел_номер
    ) s
```

Answer (score 0):

Может быть так(нет схемы-данных чтобы проверить):

```
update O
set O.Отдел_кол=C.Var1, O.Отдел_зарп=C.Var2
from Отдел O
inner join (SELECT COUNT(*) Var1, SUM(Сотрудник.Оклад) Var2,Отдел
FROM Сотрудник) C on O.Отдел_номер = С.Отдел
```

а вообще перед упдейтом и записыванием всего это в  процедуру, пробуйте просто выбрать

```
select O.*,C.var1,C.Var2
from Отдел O
inner join (SELECT COUNT(*) Var1, SUM(Сотрудник.Оклад) Var2,Отдел
FROM Сотрудник) C on O.Отдел_номер = С.Отдел
```

Comment: Не будет работать - столбца `С.Отдел` не существует

Comment: исправил, ну логика думаю автору понятна, что лучше через джойн или крос апли это делать, а не упдейт по подзапросу